# What is the word for when you're helping someone willingly?

Tags: single-word-requests

Eg. You're in an association so you are helping persons willingly and you are looking for no reward.

Comment: What kind of an association?  Business? Personal? Geographic?

Comment: Do you mean helping someone else within the same organization, like one employee helping another employee move some boxes even though "box-moving" isn't part of the employee's job description (but the employee still gets paid a salary)? Or do you mean working in an all-volunteer organization, like a volunteer fire department, helping people outside the organization for no pay?

Answer (score 7):

"Volunteer" sounds like what you're describing.

Comment: That's the noun, there's also "volunteering" (verb) and "voluntarily" (adverb).

Comment: @user568458 volunteer is the verb.

Answer (score 4):

Your work in the association can be considered "volunteer" work as Ryan already suggested, and it can be also considered "[altruistic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/altruistic)":

> from the Free Dictionary:
>
> 1. Unselfish concern for the welfare of others; selflessness.

Comment: Related: [Alruist badge](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/altruist)